# How can I remotely control a linux box from my Mac?

Tags: linux, mac, remote-desktop, remote-access

I set all of my family members up with Linux Mint so that their computers would stop punching themselves in the face, but I'd like to be able to control those computers when my mom calls up and wants to know how to "put her favorites in the drop box." I've got Parallels with WinXP, and Ubunutu VMs, so my OS isn't really a concern (although I'd prefer to use OS X if there was a slick GUI app).  What's the best or most practical approach to getting access to these computers from across the country?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Definitely SSH. You could set up an under-privileged account with `sudo-level` privileges and connect to the box using that account over SSH to administrate the box. And, if you are looking for a graphical alternative, there is of course VNC: by setting up a VNC server on the remote box, and using the [Chicken](http://sourceforge.net/projects/chicken/) VNC client on OS X, you could have a graphical remote access to the box.

Comment: I've got this working using Linux Mint's 'Remote Desktop' feature and the Mac GUI you mentioned. It's a painless procedure, albeit a bit sluggish. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

[NoMachine's NX Free Edition](http://www.nomachine.com/products.php) can be installed on Linux hosts, and they have NX Client versions for Windows, Mac, and Linux.

Comment: SSH certainly is handiest for most administration tasks, but if you happen to need/prefer a full graphical Gnome/KDE session remotely, this is probably the best way to go!

Answer (score 2):

You could use a VNC server and client (see here for more: http://www.skullbox.net/vncserver.php).  Essentially VNC is what Remode Desktop is on Windows, i.e. allowing one computer over a network (or internet) to access a 'screen' on another computer.  There are VNC servers and clients available for Linux and MacOS (you'd need a server on the Linux and a VNC client on the Mac).

Answer (score 1):

NoMachine is available for mac, linux and windows clients as well as servers at http://www.nomachine.com

Answer (score 0):

you can use [x2go](http://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php) its graphical and uses x forwarding over ssh over tcp.
Easy to install the server in linux. on mac side just take the apropriate client

Answer (score -2):

No, you can't. Mac locks you out. I mean you technically can but they make it difficult. Mac wants you communicating only with their computers unless you have no choice and use a web browser.